# Configure table line color for the whole document?

Tags: tables, color

I am using  `tabular`, `tabularx` and `tabulary` with the package `array` and I would like to declare the color of the line for all the tables in the whole document.

The goal is to make them slightly less dark.

Is there a package/command to do this? I found that I can easily change the line color for one table with `\colortbl`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l!{\color{green}\vrule}l}
    \arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
    test & test\\\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Bue I don't want to rewrite my whole document to change this everywhere.

Comment: Well, you can simply use `\arrayrulecolor` in the preamble...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\arrayrulecolor{black}
```

[image]

```
\arrayrulecolor{gainsboro}
```

[image]

```
\arrayrulecolor{antiquewhite}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}
    \definecolor{antiquewhite}{rgb}{0.98, 0.92, 0.84}
        \definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
            \definecolor{gainsboro}{rgb}{0.86, 0.86, 0.86}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{antiquewhite}

\begin{tabular}
  {|l|  c|    c|}             \hline
 one & two & three     \\ \hline
  1  & 2  & 3            \\ \hline
  4  & 5  & 6            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you load `xcolor` with options `[table, svgnames]`, 1) it loads `colortbl` (and adds some commands) 2) these colours are already defined.