# Adding arrayrulecolor command removes top rule

Tags: tables, beamer, arrays, colortbl, cline

The code below results in the image below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme[named=gray]{structure}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\frame{
%\arrayrulecolor{light-gray}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}m{2.45cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.4cm}
|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.63cm}|}\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\gr{short}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\gr{short}}\\\hline
\gr{short text} & very, very long text here & very, very long text here\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: black rules]

When I try to change the arrayrulecolor to light-gray (by removing the percent symbol at the start of line 10), I get the image below.  Note that the top rule has disappeared.
[image: light-gray]

I tried using the hhline package and replacing `\cline{2-3}` with `\hhline{~|-|-|}` but I get the same results.

How do I get the table in the first image but with the rule color set to light gray?  I am using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558255/197451

Comment: @jsbibra How does that help? `\arrayrulecolor` is exactly what is causing the problem here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be problems with coloured \clines in beamer. Here is a workaround, using `\cmidrule` from booktabs. I had to neutralise the vertical padding below the rule. I simplified a bit the  code: instead of loading `colortbl`, I  added the `table` option to beamer, which passses it to `xcolor`, which loads `colortbl`.

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme[named=gray]{structure}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\frame{\arrayrulecolor{light-gray}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}m{2.45cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.4cm}
|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.63cm}|}
 \cmidrule{2-3}\noalign{\vskip -\belowrulesep}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\gr{short}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\gr{short}}\\\hline
\gr{short text} & very, very long text here & very, very long text here\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Erm, your code does not quite correspond to the description you give in the text...

Comment: @campa: Oh! es. A copy-paste accident again! I should have checked. Fixed it. Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain what you want directly with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. A key `hvlines` draws all the expected rules excepted in the corners (specified by `corners`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme[named=gray]{structure}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular} [ rules/color=gray!20 , corners = NW , hvlines ]
  {wl{2.45cm}m[l]{3.4cm}m[l]{3.63cm}}
\RowStyle{\color{gray}\centering}
                & short & short \\
short text & very, very long text here & very, very long text here\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Following the informations given in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99041/strange-disappearing-colored-rules-in-beamer), here is a patch of `\cline` (in fact `\@cline` which is used by `\cline`) which solves the problem.

The command `\cline` is defined in standard LaTeX. It's not overwritten by the package `array` but it is by the package `colortbl`.

In the following code, I have added `kern \z@` in the redefinition done by `colortbl`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme[named=gray]{structure}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
\omit
\@multicnt#1%
\advance\@multispan\m@ne
\ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
\@multicnt#2%
\advance\@multicnt-#1%
\advance\@multispan\@ne
{\CT@arc@ \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\kern\z@}%
\cr
\noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\frame{
\arrayrulecolor{light-gray}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}m{2.45cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.4cm}
|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.63cm}|}\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\gr{short}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\gr{short}}\\\hline
\gr{short text} & very, very long text here & very, very long text here\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for this.