# Problems with \arrayrulecolor on beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, color

I am trying to write a certain table on beamer, but there is a problem with the command \arrayrulecolor I cannot understand...

Here is the table in an article document class, how I want it to look like. (Some may object to my choice to use horizontal and vertical rules: but this is just a working example of the problem, my real table is hundreds of rows long, with at least a dozen columns and many, many multicolumns and multirows, and I think, and some people I discussed the table with agree, that the rules help a little bit.)

[image]

The code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[9pt,dvipsnames,table]{article}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{amsbsy}         
\usepackage{amscd}          
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage{amssymb}        
\usepackage{amstext}        
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}       
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Y & \cellcolor{red!15}  & Y \\\hhline{-*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{red!15}}|-}*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-}}
   Y & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{red!15}N}  & Y\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But, when I try to use exactly the same code on beamer, I get the following: notice the white line in the middle column, and the absence of a black line in the last.

[image]

The code is essentially the same, but I still post it below.

```
\documentclass[9pt,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{amsbsy}         
\usepackage{amscd}          
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage{amssymb}        
\usepackage{amstext}        
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}       
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Y & \cellcolor{red!15}  & Y \\\hhline{-*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{red!15}}|-}*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-}}
   Y & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{red!15}N}  & Y\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Honestly, I have no idea of what is the problem: I tried searching online for some known bug in the interplay between beamer and \arrayrulecolor, but nothing. I tried switching the order of the packages too, to no avail... I also removed every package I could, the ones above being the absolutely necessary for my document to work, but that did not help me either.

Comment: Have a look at the tabularray package. This allows you to merge and colour cells without these problems.

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558628/adding-arrayrulecolor-command-removes-top-rule/558635#558635)

Comment: @F.Pantigny I looked at it, but it deals mainly with \cline, which actually seems to work for me; my problem is really with \hhline and \arrayrulecolor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by David Carlisle in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99041/strange-disappearing-colored-rules-in-beamer), the origin of the problem is an `\unskip` added by Beamer in the definition of the LaTeX command `\reset@color`.

If you want, here is a patch with a modification of `\HH@loop`. That command is a command of `\hhline` but it is redefined by `\colortbl`. That's why I do a modification of that redefinition. I have only added a `\kern\z@` that will be gobbled by the `\unskip`.

```
\documentclass[9pt,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{amsbsy}         
\usepackage{amscd}          
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage{amssymb}        
\usepackage{amstext}        
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}       
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\HH@loop{%
  \ifx\@tempb`\def\next##1{\the\toks@\cr}\else\let\next\HH@let
  \ifx\@tempb|\if@tempswa
          \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
           \HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}%
          \else
           \HH@add{{\CT@drsc@\vrule\@width\doublerulesep}}%
           \fi
          \fi\@tempswatrue
          \HH@add{{\CT@arc@\vline}}\else
  \ifx\@tempb:\if@tempswa
          \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
           \HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}%
          \else
           \HH@add{{\CT@drsc@\vrule\@width\doublerulesep}}%
           \fi
              \fi\@tempswatrue
      \HH@add{\@tempc\HH@box\arrayrulewidth\arrayrulewidth\@tempc}\else
  \ifx\@tempb##\if@tempswa\HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}\fi\@tempswatrue
         \HH@add{{\CT@arc@\vline\copy\@ne\@tempc\vline}}\else
  \ifx\@tempb~\@tempswafalse
           \if@firstamp\@firstampfalse\else\HH@add{&\omit}\fi
              \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
                \HH@add{\hfil}\else
                 \HH@add{{%
                   \CT@drsc@\leaders\hrule\@height\HH@height\hfil}}%
               \fi
                 \else
  \ifx\@tempb-\@tempswafalse
           \gdef\HH@height{\arrayrulewidth}%
           \if@firstamp\@firstampfalse\else\HH@add{&\omit}\fi
              \HH@add{{%
                \CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfil\kern\z@}}% \kern\z@ added
                           \else
  \ifx\@tempb=\@tempswafalse
       \gdef\HH@height{\dimen\thr@@}%
       \if@firstamp\@firstampfalse\else\HH@add{&\omit}\fi
       \HH@add
          {\rlap{\copy\@ne}\leaders\copy\@ne\hfil\llap{\copy\@ne}}\else
  \ifx\@tempb t\HH@add{%
    \def\HH@height{\dimen\thr@@}%
    \HH@box\doublerulesep\z@}\@tempswafalse\else
  \ifx\@tempb b\HH@add{%
    \def\HH@height{\dimen\thr@@}%
    \HH@box\z@\doublerulesep}\@tempswafalse\else
  \ifx\@tempb>\def\next##1##2{%
     \HH@add{%
      {\baselineskip\p@\relax
       ##2%
      \global\setbox\@ne\HH@box\doublerulesep\doublerulesep}}%
       \HH@let!}\else
  \ifx\@tempb\@sptoken\let\next\HH@spacelet\else
  \PackageWarning{hhline}%
      {\meaning\@tempb\space ignored in \noexpand\hhline argument%
       \MessageBreak}%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \next}

\makeatother

\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Y & \cellcolor{red!15}  & Y \\\hhline{-*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{red!15}}|-}*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-}}
   Y & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{red!15}N}  & Y\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

By the way, I think that there is an error in your instruction `\hhline`.

You will have a better output with the following code :

```
\hhline{-|*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{red!15}}-}*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-}}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

However, I recommend `{NiceTabular}` to construct such tables.

```
\documentclass[9pt,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines]
Y & \Block[fill=red!15]{2-1}{N} & Y \\
Y &                             & Y\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

As you see, you will have a better output in the PDF viewers.

Comment: That works, thank you very much! About the error in my \hhline instruction, you mean I should move | from *{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{red!15}}|-} to just before that expression?

Comment: Yes. The `|` should be before `\arrayrulecolor{red!15}` in order to have a small square black instead of red.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! As suggested @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, use of the `tabularray` package can be solution:

```
\documentclass[9pt,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c Q[c] c}
             }
Y   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=red!15}    N
        &   Y   \\
Y   &   &   Y   \\
Z   & Z &   Z   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

The same result you will get at use of the `article` document class.

**Note:** be aware, that beamer load some packages as are `xcolor`, `graphicx`, `amsmath` etc.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately my real table is extremely long, and rewriting it using tabularray would be very time consuming... I will wait a little longer for a solution using \arrayrulecolor, but will keep your answer in mind.

Comment: @AnyDisplayName, changing  from classic table to `tabularray` table is simple. Benefits are evident and worth for this effort (actually you only need to define table preambles and clean-up your table codes)., rewriting rules colors is quite demanding task ... but all is up to you